# Error at MySQL server

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting the following error:

> ...check the syntax that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
>   the right syntax to use near "Item1" at line 1

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
String e = e_id.getSelectedItem().toString();
String value1 = e;
String o = o_code.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
String value2 = o;
String value3 = o_credit.getText();
// String value4 = session.getText();
// String value5 = designation.getText();
// String value6 = phd_com_id.getText();
String sql = "update passes_optional set o_code='"+value2+"', o_credit='"+value3+"' where e_id='"+value1+"'";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.execute();
```

`e_id` is a drop down list with the values "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", and "Item4". The table contains info on Item1.

Comment: Please don't dump unsanitised values directly into your SQL string. The `PreparedStatement` interface provides a set of `setX(X value)` methods for safely adding parameters to your queries.

Comment: Dont concat the value in the SQL instead is prepareStatement.setXXX() to set the value.

Answer (score 3):

That's because with `prepareStatement` you have to use `PreparedStatements`.

```
String sql="update passes_optional set o_code=?, o_credit=? where e_id=?";
PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

pst.setString(1, value2);
pst.setString(2, value3);
pst.setString(3, value1);
pst.execute();
```

[Oracle official Prepared Statements tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by JonK, you should also be using `pst.executeUpdate()` instead of `pst.execute()`:

```
String sql="update passes_optional set o_code=?, o_credit=? where e_id=?";
PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

pst.setString(1, value2);
pst.setString(2, value3);
pst.setString(3, value1);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Believe the OP also needs to be calling `pst.executeUpdate()` instead of just `pst.execute()`

Comment: @JonK The OP _should_ be calling `executeUpdate`, but both `pst.executeUpdate()` and `pst.execute()` should work. From the docs: `boolean execute(): Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which may be any kind of SQL statement.`

Comment: Not working!!! It is giving java.lang.Unsupported operational exception:not supported yet

Comment: @user3598542 Did you add the mysql jdbc connector to your project? Can you post the _exact_ exception, with the full code and the line which is causing the exception?